# How to use emojis in a webpage?

Tags: html, emoji

On http://google.com's source code (view-source:https://www.google.com/), there is the a `meta` tag like this: 
`<meta content="Let the matches begin! Celebrate ⚽ around the  in today's #GoogleDoodle!" property="twitter:description">`

How were those those emojis added to the source code? How is it possible to generate such a page dynamically (what would be written on the server side for the HTML to be generated like this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [Unicode characters](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/index.html).

Comment: So how would this HTML be generated dynamically? By searching up the unicode for each emoji?

Comment: Just use Unicode escaping sequences in the HTML source. For example, `&#x26BD;` will show ⚽.

Answer (score 0):

For adding emojis into HTML, you can use the decimal (dec) or hexadecimal (hex) reference found in the table on [w3school web page](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp).

You can also check my shoe emojis example by running the code snippet below :-)

```html
<p style="font-size:50px">&#128095; &#128095;</p>
```